# calling function from a different class - Throws error 'class has no member the function'

Tags: ios, swift, function, class

I have the below class declared in a separate swift file

```
class KeerthanaiArray: NSObject {
    var SongTitle: String = String()
    var SongLyrics: String = String()
    var ESongTitle: String = String()

    init(SongTitle: String, SongLyrics:String, ESongTitle: String) {
        self.SongTitle = SongTitle
        self.SongLyrics = SongLyrics
        self.ESongTitle = ESongTitle
    }

    func match(string:String) -> Bool {
        return SongTitle.containsString(string) || ESongTitle.containsString(string)
    }
}
```

But when I reference this class in my Masterviewcontroller it throws an error message saying value of type [Keerthanaiarray] has no member 'match'

Below is my code..the code fails in searchr statement

```
      var keerthanaiArray = [KeerthanaiArray]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



  **let searchr = (keerthanaiArray.match(KeerthanaiArray.songTitle.lowercaseString))**
```

Comment: it is still not working. Could you please show me the correct code please

Comment: let frame = keerthanaiArray.KeerthanaiArray()
      let searchr = (frame.match(KeerthanaiArray.songTitle.lowercaseString))   this is what I tried. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
var keerthanaiArray = [KeerthanaiArray]()
```

This is instantiating an array of `KeerthanaiArray`. What I think you're trying to do is this:

```
var keerthanaiArray = KeerthanaiArray(SongTitle: "Some", SongLyrics: "Text", ESongTitle: "Here")
```

Comment: I was populating this array by querying a sqlite database file   like below                                                                                                                    let songTitleT = results?.stringForColumn("SONGNAME")
          
                let songLyricsT = results?.stringForColumn("SONGLYRICS")
          
                let EsongTitleT = results?.stringForColumn("ESONGNAME")
                
                    let keerthanaiArray = [KeerthanaiArray(SongTitle : songTitleT!, SongLyrics : songLyricsT!,
                        ESongTitle : EsongTitleT!)]

Comment: @Jebus Can you please format your comments? It's quite hard to make out code like that.

Comment: OK I can see what your comment says, but I'm not clear on what you're trying to say.

Comment: `$  func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String, match : (() -> Void))
          
      {
        
          for keerthanaiArrayObject in keerthanaiArray {
              let searchr = (keerthanaiArrayObject.match(searchText.lowercaseString))
        }
        
        
          self.searchResults = keerthanaiArray.filter({(keerthanaiArray:[String]) -> Bool in
        
           
              return searchr
`

Comment: sorry I am new to this post.. not sure how to paste the code inside the comment line  I am trying to display the search results in my tableview and that's how I have coded above.  I know it will not work... any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I need help on coding the function filtercontentforsearchtext for returning the search results. Search the string in both SongTitle and ESongTitle and based on the match return the filtered SongTitle